# Mediaplayer and finish() method

Tags: java, android

I was just testing mediaplayer in android, i started a stream in the onCreate method and I have a button that calls the finish() method. After clicking the button I can still hear the stream playing even though the activity is close, I am wondering if this is a leak of sorts and i will have to stop the player first before calling the finish() method, or if finish() method actually does not full kill the app to free up resources. Thank you for reading

```
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Button add_function,exit_btn;   
            add_function = (Button) findViewById(R.id.view_chat);
            exit_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit_btn);


            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
            String URL_OF_FILE = "http://stream.radiosai.net:8002/";
    try {
        mp.setDataSource(URL_OF_FILE);
         mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

            mp.start();



        exit_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });
             }// EOF ONCREATE
```

Comment: Please show the code.  Where do you declare the MediaPlayer instance?

Comment: I will edit my main post to include this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `finish()` does not kill the application, it just destroys the current `Activity` that you're finishing. Although I would think finishing the Activity would stop the `MediaPlayer`, what you should probably do in this case is override `onDestroy()`, and release your `MediaPlayer` object there. For instance:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if(mediaPlayer != null) mediaPlayer.release();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you should probably release the mediaPlayer before calling the parent's onDestroy?

Comment: also just a quick clear up, is this an efficient way to do this? or just to aid in my problem? It does surprise me as well as to why the activity was closed and the stream still going which is why i asked this question.

Comment: @manavo Probably so, edited to reflect that. :) 

kabuto178, efficient? I mean there's nothing *inefficient* about it, but what do you mean exactly? Typically if you're going to release resources like this you'd do it in the corresponding end event (e.g. `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()`, `onResume()` and `onPause()`)

Comment: i'd rather stop the mediaplayer in either onPause or onStop

Comment: @njzk2 If you do it that way then you'd want to also initialize the MediaPlayer in `onResume()` or `onStart()` respectively, or you're going to end up with seemingly random exceptions. For instance, if the Activity is stopped and then resumed (before `onDestroy()` is called) then you'll be trying to use a MediaPlayer that you've already released without reinitializing it yet.

Comment: that is true. but i'm not entirely sure when onDestroy is called, while i'm pretty confident i know when onPause is called.

Comment: Follow up question, after i make the activity i posted above finish and starts a new activity that has an AsyncTask, calling the media player again works for maybe 5 seconds and then the music stops.

Comment: Depends on what your AsyncTask is doing and how you're prepping the player. You should make this a separate question, though.